# I really don't understand what i'm doing false here for an iOS response

Tags: ionic3, angular4-router

```
    // service.ts//

      postRequest1(credentials, subUrl) {
        this.URL = this.apiUrl + subUrl;
         let headers = new Headers({
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Access-control-allow-headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With',
   'Access-control-allow-methods' :'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
   'Access-control-allow-origin': '*   ',
        });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.post(this.URL, credentials, options)
                .map(res => res)
                .subscribe(res => {
                    resolve(res);
                }, (error) => {
                    reject(error);
                });
        });
    }
```

I am facing the error Web service `-XMLHttpRequest` cannot load (my url) due to access control checks. Response. How can I eliminate this issue and get the post method information data?This issue is working properly in Android and getting an error on an ios device.This error is shown after submit on an iOS

And also I'm facing an error of type `thisXMLHttpRequest` cannot load [my url]. Preflight response is not successful

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that Access-Control has to be set server-side. Maybe error is somewhere there.

Comment: there also another issue about preflight response